# How to process multiple 3rd party APIs without waiting for their response in ASP.NET API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

Let's assume I have add order API & I need to call 3 APIs if the order is saved successfully. I want to return the response as soon as the order processing is finished without waiting for the 3 APIs to finish.

For example:

```
var result = ProcessOrder(parameters);
if (result.IsSuccess)
{
   await SendSMSAsync(smsDetails);   //All 3 APIs includes calling the API, saving status to database & log
   await SendEmailAsync(emailDetails);
   await ThirdPartyAsync(moreDetails);
}
return result;   //I want to return this without waiting for the above 3 APIs to finish
```

Also, I would like to call again any failed API automatically. What's the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Check for [Saga Pattern for microservices](https://medium.com/design-microservices-architecture-with-patterns/saga-pattern-for-microservices-distributed-transactions-7e95d0613345).

Comment: "The best approach" is probably going to depend on a lot of factors. If third party products are an option for you, then you might check out [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) (not affiliated) or something similar. Otherwise, you could do something like store the details for each API in a DB or file with some metadata about the job, then have a Windows Service or separate process pick them up from the DB / file and process them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by using `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. For example:

```
if (result.IsSuccess)
{
   SendSMSAsync(smsDetails).ConfigureAwait(false);
   SendEmailAsync(emailDetails).ConfigureAwait(false);
   ThirdPartyAsync(moreDetails).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

More information can be found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of await, create a task and call Task.Run. This will run without waiting for the task to return.